# I can't submit the form even if it is valid

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have used CreateView for a form, but the form is not being submitted even when it is valid. It just redirects to the same page again.I am using the form_id for from fields, and it even submitted once or twice but now it is just not working.

models.py

```
class Centre(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length =250)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 10 digits allowed.")
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class centre(CreateView):
    fields = ('name','address','contact','phone',)
    model = Centre
    success_url = reverse_lazy("NewApp:logindex")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(centre, self).form_valid(form)
```

template :

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col col-md-12">
    <div class="fieldWrapper" >
    {{ form.name.errors }}
    <div class="form-group col col-md-3">
        <label for="{{form.name.id_for_label}">Centre Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Centre Name" name="name" maxlength="250"  id="id_name" style="box-sizing: border-box; width:500px;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col col-md-3" style="float:right; margin-top=-80px;width=200%">
        <label for="{{form.address.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200%;white-space:nowrap;">Centre&nbsp;Address</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Centre Address" name="address" maxlength="250" id="id_address" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br><br><br>
    <div class="col col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group col col-md-3" style="float:right; margin-top=-80px;">
    <label for="{{form.contact.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200px;white-space:nowrap;">Contact&nbsp;Person</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Person" name="address" maxlength="250" id="id_contact" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">
     </div>
    {{ user_form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper" >

     <div class="form-group col col-md-3" >
        <label for="{{form.phone.id_for_label}" style="white-space:nowrap;">Contact&nbsp;Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone"  maxlength="10" id="id_phone" placeholder="Contact Number" style="width:500px";>
        {{ form.phone.errors }}
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="col col-md-12" style="padding-left:4.5% ;padding-top:2%">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" style=" height:30px;width:80px;padding-bottom:2em;"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You did not specify an `action=...` in your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong `name` attribute for the `contact` field, as a result of which it is not being submitted. At the same time, you are not outputting errors for that field.

(Note, you really should use the Django form tags to output the input elements; that would have avoided this situation, as well as pre-populating the fields when the template is redisplayed after validation.)